How to use Dockerfile ADD with ssh_config
I am trying to use an ADD command that points to a private repository via ssh:// in a Dockerfile, and I need it to also check the ssh_config to use the correct username and key file. For example in an ssh_config file:
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE            
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa

Given the above ssh_config file and the following:
compose.yml:
services:
  exmpl:
    container_name: exmpl_container
    build:
      ssh:
        - default
      no_cache: true

Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh
COPY ssh_config /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ssh_config.conf
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=1000 ssh -v git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com >> ssh_log 2>&1 || true
ADD ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repository-name>
ENTRYPOINT ["cat", "ssh_log"]

Running:
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
docker compose up --build -d

Yields:
failed to solve: failed to load cache key: failed to fetch remote ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repository-name>: git error: exit status 128
stderr:
root@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

As you can see, ADD is trying to connect via root@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, when it should be using APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com given the ssh_config.
For further debugging, you can comment out run the ADD line and run docker compose up --build to see that the RUN --mount=type=ssh command is correctly connecting. You will see output that includes
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported. Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.


indicating that the correct  and ssh-agent socket key have been used to successfully connect to the server.
The documentation here indicates that ADD ssh:// should behave like an mount=type=ssh command.

Did you know AWS is sunsetting code commit?  No plan yet to actually turn off the service in existing accounts, but they're disabling it in new accounts.  So you may want to think about migrating

looking at the man page for ssh_config, I don't see /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ssh_config.conf.  I see /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

@erik258 the default /etc/ssh/ssh_config (at least in the image we are using) includes the line Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf to include other config's in ssh_config.d . And yes, I did know that AWS is sunsetting code commit, so migrating is probably on the table in the future.
